# Linear regression in python (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, linear-regression, tensorflow2.0

I am running a code i saw on buitin website on linear regression with tensorflow and it keeps giving me an error, I don't know what is wrong with the code. first i thought it was my ide , then when i switched to jupyter lab it showed me error at this point

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
rng = np.random

X= np.array([3.3,4.4,5.5,6.71,6.93,4.168,9.779,6.182,7.59,2.167,
            7.042,10.791,5.313,7.997,5.654, 9.27,3.1])

Y=np.array([1.7,2.76,2.09,3.19,1.694,1.573,3.366,2.596,2.53,1.22, 
            1, 2.827,3.465,1.65,2.904,2.42,2.94,1.3])

n_samples = X.shape[0]

# Setting up the hyperparameters
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 1000
display_step = 50

# Weigth and bias initialized randomly
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

# Linear regression (Wx + b)
def linear_regression(x):
    return W*x + b

# Mean swuare error.
def mean_square(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred-y_true,  2) / (2*n_samples))

# Stochastic Gradient Descent Optimizer
optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

# Optimization process
def run_optimization():
# Wrap computation inside a GradientTape for automatic differentiation
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        pred = linear_regression(X)
        loss = mean_square(pred, Y)

    # compute gradient
    gradients = g.gradient(loss, [W,b])

    # update W and b following gradients
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [W,b]))

# Run training for the given number of steps
for step in range(1, epochs + 1):

# Run the optimization to update W and b values
    run_optimization()
    if step % display_step == 0:
        pred = linear_regression(X)
        loss = mean_square(pred, Y)
        print("step: %i, loss: %f, W:%f, b:%f"% (step, loss, W.numpy(), b.numpy()))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Graphic display

plt.plot(X, Y, 'ro', label="Original data")
plt.plot(X, np.array(W * X +b), label="Fitted line")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

first i thought it was my ide , then when i switched to jupyter lab it showed me error at this point

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-794baf7bf908> in <module>
      5     # Run the optimization to update W and b values.
      6 
----> 7     run_optimization()
      8 
      9     if step % display_step == 0:

<ipython-input-25-53e6e421f909> in run_optimization()
     13         pred = linear_regression(X)
     14 
---> 15         loss = mean_square(pred, Y)
     16 
     17     # Compute gradients.

<ipython-input-24-184c15846bf2> in mean_square(y_pred, y_true)
      9 def mean_square(y_pred, y_true):
     10 
---> 11     return tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred-y_true, 2)) / (2 * n_samples)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
   1232         #   r_binary_op_wrapper use different force_same_dtype values.
   1233         x, y = maybe_promote_tensors(x, y, force_same_dtype=False)
-> 1234         return func(x, y, name=name)
   1235       except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
   1236         # Even if dispatching the op failed, the RHS may be a tensor aware

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in subtract(x, y, name)
    546 @dispatch.add_dispatch_support
    547 def subtract(x, y, name=None):
--> 548   return gen_math_ops.sub(x, y, name)
    549 
    550 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
  10549       return _result
  10550     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 10551       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  10552     except _core._FallbackException:
  10553       pass

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6895   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6896   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6897   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6898   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6899 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [17] vs. [18] [Op:Sub]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just as the interpreter complains - you have a mismatch in shapes between the inputs to `mean_square` - your `X` / samples vector is 17 elements and your `Y` / targets vector is 18 elements, as you can verify.

Comment: please can  you highlight that particular error , because it is really hard reading those errors

Comment: The dimensions mismatch appears in the bottom line (literally). Then you can track it back up the call stack - which is printed - up to the last function that belongs to your code, that's the 3rd block of text from the top. Or you could immediately make  sure that your inputs are the same size as your outputs - which is the likely mismatch that can happen.